# Busy indicator for WCF async calls in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I have a SL4 app consuming WCF services. The client make async call to the services, during this time I would like to show some sort information or busy indicator on the screen which tells the users that the app is doing something.

Now I am pretty sure SL4 has something like this, but I am drawing a blank....

Can someone please point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the BusyIndicator control which is part of the Silverlight Toolkit Experimental quality band.

You can try the control on the following link:
http://www.silverlight.net/content/samples/sl4/toolkitcontrolsamples/run/default.html

Comment: Thanks! what did you mean by Experimental quality band??

Comment: @VoodooChild: It means that the control may be subject to change in future versions. From the following link: http://silverlight.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Quality%20Bands&referringTitle=Home&ANCHOR#Experimental. "Experimental components are intended for evaluation purposes. The main goal of these components is to provide an opportunity for feedback during the earliest stages of development. This feedback will help decide the future of these components. Development of an experimental component may end at any point so it may not be included in future releases."

Comment: I think I would be using BusyIndicator it looks interesting. One problem with using with WCF async calls would be that if two calls are made to the service then the first one to get completed would set the "IsBusy" to false hence taking the indicator off the screen while the second call might be happening. I guess we can do further logic to set that flag to false on the last call to get completed...

Comment: @VoodooChild: This is always a problem. You actually don't know when which one is the last to return. You also have to take in considereation that one of them may fail. I would take a look on Agatha project that let your make multiple calls "at the same time". The link is: http://code.google.com/p/agatha-rrsl/ and the link to the creator: http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/11/requestresponse-service-layer-series/

Answer (score 0):

You need an animation storyboard and then use code like this:

```
wcfProxyClass.DoMethodAsync()
loadingStoryboard.Begin();
```

Then in the Completed event handler

```
loadingStoryboard.End(); // not sure on this syntax
```

Here's a great article that should get you started. -- http://chrisa.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/a-wait-indicator-in-silverlight/

Comment: Bross: is there a build in storyBoard that I can use? Can you provide any links to further explain how to use this please? thanks